# ConcurrentModificationException while updating values

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrentmodification

The `update` function should update each value in the `HashMap` by calling the function `test` to determine the new value. The `test` function returns either a 1 or 0 depending on the 8 locations/neighbors around it. Although, I get a `ConcurrentModificationException` every time the program gets to the update function.

```
private static void update(){
   for(Cell e : map.keySet()){
       map.put(e,test(e.getX(),e.getY()));
  }
}

private static int test(int i, int j){
    //count alive neighbors
    int sum = 0;
    if(map.get(new Cell(i-1, j - 1)) == null){
        map.put(new Cell(i-1, j - 1), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i-1, j - 1));
    } else {
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i-1, j - 1));
    }

    if(map.get(new Cell(i, j - 1)) == null){
        map.put(new Cell(i, j - 1), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i, j - 1));
    } else {
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i, j - 1));
    }

    if(map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j - 1)) == null){
        map.put(new Cell(i + 1, j - 1), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j - 1));
    } else {
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j - 1));
    }

    if(map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j)) == null){
        map.put(new Cell(i + 1, j), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j));
    } else {
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j));
    }

    if(map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j + 1)) == null){
        map.put(new Cell(i + 1, j + 1), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j + 1));
    } else {
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i + 1, j + 1));
    }

    if(map.get(new Cell(i, j + 1)) == null){
        map.put(new Cell(i, j + 1), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i, j + 1));
    } else {
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i, j + 1));
    }

    if(map.get(new Cell(i - 1, j + 1)) == null){
        map.put(new Cell(i - 1, j + 1), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i - 1, j + 1));
    } else {
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i - 1, j + 1));
    }

    if(map.get(new Cell(i - 1, j)) == null){
        map.put(new Cell(i - 1, j), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i - 1, j));
    } else {
        sum += map.get(new Cell(i - 1, j));
    }

    //return to be alive or dead
    int temp = 0;
    if(map.get(new Cell(i,j)) == 1){
        if(sum < 2){
            temp = 0;
        } else if(sum == 2 || sum == 3){
            temp = 1;
        } else if(sum > 3){
            temp = 0;
        }
    } else {
        if(sum == 3){
            temp = 1;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: During the `for(Cell e : map.keySet()) { ... }` you cannot make structural modifications to the `HashMap`.  Perhaps you could use a `ConcurrentHashMap` ... or rethink your algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `ConcurrentModificationException` because you are modifying the `Map` while you are iterating over it, which is not allowed.

You can **make a copy of your current map** for iteration.
Instead of doing operations on the same map, **iterate over one and do manipulation over the second**, then use the second map as output.

Read about [ConcurrentModificationException](https://www.journaldev.com/378/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception) for more understanding.

Comment: The OP appears to be implementing "Game of Life".  In this case, `ConcurrentHashMap` is the wrong choice, and making a copy is the right one, since the modifications being made should not be used in subsequent modifications during the current step.  "Making a copy of the current map, and iterate over one and modify the second" is the correct approach.

Comment: @AJNeufeld would there be a better choice than a HashMap for implementing something like "Game of Life" or is it best to stay with what I already have?

Comment: @TylerWetherington Let's move this question to my answer, to avoid pestering mav3n with our comment notifications.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of answering your question (which has already been done), I'd like to help you improve your coding.

Because you are using `map.get(new Cell(i-1, j-1))`, I'm going to hope you have provided implementations for `Cell#hashcode()` and `Cell#equals()`.  If not, please read up on how `HashMap` works, and then implement those methods immediately.

Consider the following code:

```
if (map.get(new Cell(i-1, j-1)) == null){
    map.put(new Cell(i-1, j-1), ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
    sum += map.get(new Cell(i-1, j-1));
}
else{
    sum += map.get(new Cell(i-1, j-1));
}
```

Here, you are calling `new Cell(i-1, j-1)` four times!  Presumably, each of these `Cell` objects will be equal to one another, but why not create it once, and reuse it for the subsequent calls:

```
Cell neighbour = new Cell(i-1, j-1);
if (map.get(neighbour) == null){
    map.put(neighbour, ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
    sum += map.get(neighbour);
}
else{
    sum += map.get(neighbour);
}
```

The garbage collector will be a little happier now.  But still, I'm seeing 3 calls to `map.get(neighbour)`!  Why?  The last two are identical ... `sum += map.get(neighbour);` at the end of each branch of the `if` statement.  If we move it out of the statement, things become better!

```
Cell neighbour = new Cell(i-1, j-1);
if (map.get(neighbour) == null){
    map.put(neighbour, ((Math.random()<0.5)?0:1));
}
sum += map.get(neighbour);
```

This is a considerable improvement.

(You could further reduce the code using `computeIfAbsent()`, which would fetch the value, creating it if necessary.  Feel free to research it, if desired; you'll need to understand lambdas.)

The code for each one of the neighbour cells is identical.  So you could put that code into its own function and call it.

```
int sum = 0;
sum += neighbour_value(i-1, j-1);
sum += neighbour_value(i,   j-1);
sum += neighbour_value(i+1, j-1);
... etc ...
```

Hope that helps.

Happy coding.

Comment: From the comment "_would there be a better choice than a `HashMap` for implementing something like Game of Life or is it best to stay with what I already have?_" in the other answer.  Yes! Absolutely there is.  But what will depend on how big your game world is.  Is it infinitely large?  Does it wrap around at the edges?  Does it just end at the edges with zero values if a neighbour beyond the edge is queried?

Comment: I was going for a infinitely large game world but I'm not exactly sure on how to do so yet.

Comment: Infinitely large is hard on memory.  If your code starts with just cell (0,0), it will create all 8 neighbours on the first iteration, and your world is 3x3.  On the next iteration, all those neighbours are create, and the world is 5x5, then 7x7, then 9x9, and so on, growing at a quadratic rate.  It would be trivial to represent the game board as a two dimensional array of boolean values, copy in the previous iteration array, shifted by one row and column, and initialize the edges to their random state.  One byte per cell is good, but we can do better ...

Comment: Instead of `boolean[][]` which uses one byte per cell, you could use `BitSet[]`, an array of BitSets, where each cell is stored as a bit, 8 cells per byte.  That will allow an extra iteration or two before you run out of memory.

Comment: I appreciate the checkmark, but my answer does not answer your posted question.  I actually expected to be flagged “not an answer”.  Please move the checkmark back to the answer from @mav3n .   If you found the information in my answer useful, upvoting is appropriate... but not accepting it as the answer to your posted question.